# CSS menu that scrolls aside content

Tags: html, css, scroll

How can I make the menu scroll aside the content.

**NOTE the content and menu are inside a container box(class=boxed) that is aligned the center of the page.** Above this container there is a header with 100% page width.

```css
.boxed{
    width:100%;
    max-width: 1154px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    }
            
    .boxed .sidebar{
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    }
```

**The HTML look something like this:**

```
<html>
<body>
  <header>header content</header>
  <div class="boxed">
    <nav id="sidebarmenu">
      <ul id="sidebar">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by scroll aside?

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    outline: 1px solid;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
#right {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    outline: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #007DAD;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <a href="link1">Side menu 1</a><br/>
  <a href="link2">Side menu 2</a><br/>
  <a href="link3">Side menu 3</a><br/>
</div>
<div id="right">Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#menu").click(function() {

  $(".sidebar").toggleClass("marginL25N");
  $(".content").toggleClass("width100P");


});
```

```css
.boxed {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1154px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.boxed .sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fda529
}
.width100P {
  width: 100%!important;
}
.marginL25N {
  margin-left: -25%;
}
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5px;
}
.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxed">
  <div class="header">my header</div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#" id="menu">click</a>
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

hope it helps